# Python - Loop not ending

Tags: python, function, loops

Within my code I am having a error ending a loop. I have build this program to run commands from a external file using functions. In the function "end" I have made a variable called "end_command" that should end the loop.

```
#command list
master_list = ['commands_list_1']
commands_list_1 = ['end']
#var
c_l_i = "start_up"
end_command = True
inList = [[] for _ in range(len(master_list))]
userName = "Alex"

#functions
def end ():
    end_command = False
    return 0;

def find_in (key):
    eval(key+'()')
    return 0;

#code
while (True == end_command):
    c_l_i = input("<-: " + userName + " :->")
    counter_c = 0
    for mlist in master_list:   
        if (c_l_i in eval (mlist)):
            inList[counter_c] = "true"
            #find_in(c_l_i)
        else:
            inList[counter_c] = "false"
        counter_c += 1
    if ('true' in inList):
       find_in(c_l_i)
    else:
         print ('command not found')
```

Comment: Please do *not* add a blank line in between any two lines of code. It makes the code less readable and spread on way more space than needed.

Comment: I would recommend using `while (True)` and `break`, instead of using a custom function for this.

Answer (score 2):

The `end()` function is setting a local variable named `end_command`, not the global variable. You need a `global` declaration:

```
def end():
    global end_command
    end_command = False
    return 0
```

BTW, using `eval` with user input is extremely poor design.